# Not able to access AWS EC2 instance IP

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ipconfig

I have started node.js server on my EC2 instance and tried accessing it using my EC2 instance IP, Did not work. showed me **this site can't be reached**.

To check my correct IP, I tried `dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com`
It returned the same IP I was trying to access.

To check if it is issue with routing, I started ngnix hoping I'd be able to check default page. Still no result. However, I tried `curl localhost` It returned me the default html page that ngnix shows up on start but I cannot check it on browser. It is not accessible.

I have also tried giving access to all ports from anywhere in inbound and outbound security groups.
Inbound rules:

[image: Inbound rules]

Outbound rules:

[image: Outbound rules]

Internet gateway is also connected with the VPC

Not sure what Went wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the instance in a public subnet or private?

Comment: I am using default subnet and I guess it is public

Answer (score 1):

check the port from inbound and outbound plus the getaway with elastic IP

What is inbound rules in AWS?
Inbound rules control the incoming traffic to your instance, and outbound rules control the outgoing traffic from your instance. When you launch an instance, you can specify one or more security groups. If you don't specify a security group, Amazon EC2 uses the default security group.

Comment: Just to check I have allowed all ports and protocols from in both inbound and outbound

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure these several things:

- You have an accessible public IP (or elastic IP if you want to dynamically control it later) and make sure it is assigned to your EC2 instance.
- Allow access for inbound and outbound port in your security groups (HTTP Port 80, HTTPS, SSH, FTP (optional), your node port, and any other port that necessary to be open from outside.)
- Run your nodejs script (I usually use PM2). so that I can monitor which script is on and which is off.
- If you want to test with nginx / apache, make sure you start the service and listening to port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was wrong! I restarted the instance and SSH client in my local. Then node server and ngnix started working! Thanks everyone for your suggestions!